# How should I insulate my old brick house?

Tags: insulation, brick, vapor-barrier, old-house

My house was built in 1920 out of a single layer of 8-inch thick hollow brick. I am looking to insulate the walls in the upstairs entirely from scratch -- there's no insulation on them at all right now, but we had to tear out all the interior wallboard for other reasons and will probably have to put in new framing/furring strips to hang drywall so we have a lot of flexibility as to insulation type. I'm just not sure either how much insulation to add (the EnergyStar.gov [guide](https://www.energystar.gov/campaign/seal_insulate/identify_problems_you_want_fix/diy_checks_inspections/insulation_r_values) is for wood-framed houses) or how to handle vapor barriers.

I read this [article](https://www.buildingscience.com/documents/digests/bsd-106-understanding-vapor-barriers) about vapor barriers but none of the examples line up with my situation exactly and I don't feel like I understand the theory well enough to come to a decision on my own. Some blogs say I should drill weep holes, and some say that old brick houses are meant to "breathe" and I shouldn't use a vapor barrier at all.

What's the best way to proceed? Assume we can't insulate from the exterior for historic reasons. I'm in Maryland, so insulation zone 4.

Comment: Can you take a photo or two of the interior side of the exposed brick with your wallboard removed? In Zone 4 you will probably not need a moisture barrier between the exterior brick because moisture will be moving from inside the warm, moist house to outside where it is usually colder and dryer. You *should* be fine with studding out walls and filling them with faced insulation or some other insulation material.

Comment: I wouldn't use faced insulation with the outside wall being concrete block.  At least not if the facing is impermeable.  IMO, the wall cavities need to able to breath a bit.  Note, I'm in Maryland also.

Comment: And isn't your (OP's) situation very similar to figure 14 or 14 in the referenced document?  Your 8" thick hollow brick wall would be similar to the poured concrete wall construction shown in those figures.